# Get count of a column with a particular value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I need to get the count of a column for a particular id, but only when the column value is "Yes". Following is wrong i guess. mid(PRIMARY KEY)

```
SELECT COUNT(mt.currentstate = 'Yes') AS currentstate FROM mytable mt WHERE mid = 100 GROUP BY mid;
```

**For the COUNT value only i need from the column mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but for the ResultSet I need to get all the values where mt.currentstate = 'Yes' or 'No'**

Comment: I think `mt.currentstate = 'Yes'` should be in where clause.

Comment: Now If i put mt.currentstate = 'Yes' inside WHERE clause, it will filter all the rows where mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but I need other column values from the rows mt.currentstate = 'No'..What I'm gonna do?

Comment: @Axel answered what you looking for

Comment: "The COUNT value only i need from the column mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but for the ResultSet I need to get all the values where mt.currentstate = 'Yes' or 'No'" - Then you have to make two queries. One aggregates for currentstate = 'Yes', and one gives you all rows independent of currentstate. Or could you provide an example of the output you expect to make it clear?

Comment: @Axel Yes Axel, I guess "Then you have to make two queries. One aggregates for currentstate = 'Yes'..." suggestion is correct, I followed that way, Thanks a lot for the help..

Answer (score 3):

You can try below query, it will work if i'm not worng.

```
SELECT COUNT(mt.mid) AS counter FROM mytable mt WHERE mid = 100 AND mt.currentstate = "YES" GROUP BY mid;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to remove the `GROUP BY` part because the result doesn't include `mid`.

Comment: Yes, may be. but actual question is how to get **total count** using this condition. but yes you are also right. +1

Comment: Now If i put mt.currentstate = 'Yes' inside WHERE clause, it will filter all the rows where mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but I need other column values from the rows mt.currentstate = 'No'..What I'm gonna do?

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra See the dit to my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS currentstate FROM mytable WHERE mid = 100 AND currentstate='Yes';
```

EDIT: "Now If i put mt.currentstate = 'Yes' inside WHERE clause, it will filter all the rows where mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but I need other column values from the rows mt.currentstate = 'No'..What I'm gonna do?"

```
SELECT currentstate, COUNT(*) AS c FROM mytable WHERE mid = 100 GROUP BY currentstate;
```

Comment: Now If i put mt.currentstate = 'Yes' inside WHERE clause, it will filter all the rows where mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but I need other column values from the rows mt.currentstate = 'No'..What I'm gonna do?

Comment: BTW: You should give more information on the table definition like can there be more than one rows for a unique `mid`? What are the table keys?

Comment: I don't think your latest updated query will work as per what @DilukshanMahendra required.

Comment: @Chandresh Yes, if `mid` is a primary key, it won't work as expected. But the real problem is that it's hard to tell what is expected...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(mt.mid) AS currentstate FROM mytable mt
WHERE mid = 100 and mt.currentstate = 'Yes' GROUP BY mid;
```

Comment: Now If i put mt.currentstate = 'Yes' inside WHERE clause, it will filter all the rows where mt.currentstate = 'Yes', but I need other column values from the rows mt.currentstate = 'No'..What I'm gonna do?